# How to upload files as url to <input type="text]

Tags: javascript, audio

I would like to upload file to filetag with url Is there a way?

ex url ) http://localhost:800/mysong.mp3

```
<input type="file">
```

Comment: can you please explain more about what you're trying to implement here

Comment: i use this code -> https://github.com/meowtec/audio-cutter ,  but this code only input tag upload, i want to file url in server  ex) localhost:8000/mysong.mp3

Comment: You can only send `file` and `name of the file` from the front-end and >>> back end will process that data  >>>& >>> save that file, >>> backend sends you the URL of the file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all pretty cool app (audio-cutter) build in React. Seems like intended to do the job at client side. I couldn't get it working on my laptop for some reason. I have a suggestion for you. Create an input field which takes in the url `<input type="text">` and save the url value somewhere, may be create another attribute called `url` in the component's state. Also create a `<button>` to initiate downloading the file from the url input, and load that into the state `file` using a handler function which uses `setState`. Basically trigger almost same code as below in the handler function for the button:

```
    this.setState({
      file: "downloaded file object goes here!",
      paused: true,
      decoding: true,
      audioBuffer: null,
    })
```

[image]

Comment: OH sorry i dont know react !! you wrtie Simple test code for me vanila javascript? and another question , Can I cut and download music with audio.currentTime?

<audio src="mysong.mp3">
mysong.mp3 is length 10sec,

using audio.currentTime to ( 5s play ~ 10 end ),

and fileDownload -> mysong.mp3 is length 5sec,      my english very low sry